# How to calc $\tilde{A}_n$ in $w\left(x,t\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\tilde{A}_n\cos\left(nx\right)\cdot e^{\left(4-n^2\right)t}=\frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

The full problem goes as follows:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    w_t=w_{xx}+4w \\
    w\left(x,0\right)= \frac{1}{4}\\
    w_x\left(0,t\right)= 0\\
    w_x\left(\pi ,t\right)= 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Thanks to Fourier Method, I got (assuming that $w\left(x,t\right)=X\left(x\right)T\left(t\right)$):

$$X_n\left(x\right)=\tilde{A}_n\cos \left(nx\right)$$

and

$$T_n\left(t\right)=e^{\left(4-n^2\right)t}$$

Because $w\left(x,t\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }w_n\left(x,t\right)$ and $w_n\left(x,t\right)=X_n\left(x\right)T_n\left(t\right)$, we get:

$$w\left(x,t\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\tilde{A}_n\cos \left(nx\right)\cdot e^{\left(4-n^2\right)t}$$

I've looked up in the solutions, and I definitely know that $w\left(x,t\right)=\frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$

But if I calculate here (using the w(x,0)=$\frac{1}{4}$ condition):

$$\tilde{A}_n=c_n=\frac{2}{\pi }\int _0^{\pi }\frac{1}{4}cos\left(nx\right)dx=\frac{\sin \left(n\pi \right)}{2n\pi }$$

I get

$$w\left(x,t\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin \left(n\pi \right)\cos \left(nx\right)}{2n\pi }e^{\left(4-n^2\right)t} = 0 \text{    (according to WolframAlpha)}$$

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the fourier component integral is non-zero for $n=0$...

Comment: I don't understand, what is that?

Comment: wolfram alpha is not entirely correct. When $n=0$, $\frac{\sin n\pi}{2n\pi}\to\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: So how can I check if this sum actually converges to $\frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$?

Comment: Well, there is only one non-zero term in the sum, so it's not really a sum. Only $n=0$ contributes

Comment: But that would mean that I don't get $\frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$ as my $w$ here, right? So where's the mistake?

Comment: Because I would get $\frac{1}{2}e^{4t}$, and not $\frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$

Comment: the normalization factor $2/\pi$ only correct for $n\neq 0$. It should be $1/\pi$ for $A_0$. I suggest you take a look at how to obtain Fourier series coefficients in detail.

Comment: It's $a_0=\frac{1}{2l}\int _{-l}^lf\left(x\right)dx\:$, I know that l = pi, but what if f(x) here?

Comment: Why do we take n=0 and not n=1? Because we did begin our sum from n=1 to infinity during class, so I'm confused a little bit right now